# Avoid cumulative sum by Unix shell script -hdfs file copy

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, hdfs

We are copying Hdfs directory (contains files) from 1 location to other however there is only 1 Target directory.
For 1st iteration it gives correct count of file size and counts of files as in 1st time target directory is not having any previous files.
But For second iteration it gives cumulative addition i.e (includes counts of 1st iteration).

How can I take counts as per latest copy of files or avoid cumulative sum/counts

How can I avoid cumulative sum and counts as we are just using

```
hdfs dfs -count "{destination}"
```

command.